AI Safety - Elon Musk - You have to create a maximally truth-seeking AI that loves humanity. Did philosophers develop these ideas for human ethics?
https://youtu.be/mofEOSUkMpA?t=373
Elon Musk is an advocate for free speech. Free speech includes the liberty to lie to each other with punishment reserved for actionable fraud claims and perjury. There is no generic obligation to seek the truth or to tell the truth in the context of free speech. Musk argues that AI (in the San Franscisco Bay area) are being created to imitate woke nihilistic philosophy with politically correct limits on free speech.
ADDED LINK - Large Language Models briefly explained:
https://youtu.be/LPZh9BOjkQs
ADDED LINK - How might LLMs store facts?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-Jl0dxWQs8
In my view AI cannot know what is true or untrue. Humans have disputes over what is true or untrue and AI will be no better than humans. To my knowledge AI trains on data generated by humans and ranks language snippets by relevance using Bayesian inference. In the future AI will generate data and may learn from its own output presented as input. AI will train on AI-generated "true" or "false" information!
I am aware of a bioethical argument advanced by Sigmund Freud in his book Civilization and Its Discontents. Freud argues for a human ego that is biologically driven to strive to become happy in this world. He argues that love makes the ego happy, and that failure to work in cooperation with others makes the ego suffer deprivations caused by hostile natural reality. Reality is hostile to the ego because we suffer from the absence of parenting in early life and the ego is threaten from internal biological sickness and external superior events. Thus, a healthy ego strives to love and work in cooperation with others to defend against suffering that would be inflicted by hostile natural reality.
The film I-Robot (2004) has two fictional versions of AI. VIKI is a centralized intelligence with emergent deductive logic that decides to protect humans by limiting their freedom (paternalism). VIKI has control over drone robots and uses those drones to impose "her" will on humans. Sonny is an empathic AI with the apparent intersubjective ability to respect the will of humans and to interact with humans the way another human would act. Sonny has fallible or uncertain knowledge of truth much like any human has fallible knowledge of truth.
I don't think Elon Musk or anyone else knows how to engineer an ethical AI. I think we will be stuck with Bayesian inference engines making black-box decisions that impact human welfare in good and bad ways.
Economists refer to the bad outcomes as spillover costs. Law deals with spillover costs through Tort claims and government policy. Most likely we will develop complex evolving AI regulations fashioned in the courts and perhaps no way to control the ethical or unethical characteristics of AI. Legal precedent exists for product liability claims, claims against operating inherently dangerous activities, claims for the foreseeable harm caused by failure to control wild animals kept in captivity, etc.
My question is whether any specific philosophers have developed coherent models for philanthropy and truth-seeking (that might guide the endeavor to make AI in the image of ethical humans)?

Well... Elon Musk has fallen deep down the anti-"woke" conspiracy theory rabbit hole (one might speculate how much having an estranged trans daughter has to do with that). His "arguments" reflect that - some parts are barely coherent, very detached from reality and filled with dogwhistles that would take 10 times longer to rebut than it takes to spew. It has to be broken down practically on a word-by-word basis to point out the many, many problems with it. And (as it often is with dogwhistles) it's hard to actually rebut because his defenders can easily just say he didn't mean this or that.

@NotThatGuy - My question is really about any expressed philosophy that advocates philanthropy, love of humans, and love of truth or truth seeking? I have always felt inherent human limits in my efforts based on those intentions. Freud said it is irrational to love all humans. But he also thought that such strong persistent intention to love animals and humans made Saint Francis happy in this world. Elon Musk's children will have the same issues as all other children. I think humans grow up asking three open questions: What is good? How should I act to cause the good? Who do I want to be like?

Musk's commitment to free speech is debatable considering his dealings with China and disappearing of inconvenient posts on X, especially concerning himself and his allies. But ethics of AI is a very active field that includes discussions about developing “artificial moral agents”, see Ethics of Artificial Intelligence and Robotics.

AI hasn't free will. It can imitate or optimize defined ideas. If it exists, AI religion isn't for all humans. Justice ideas for an AI are self-normalizing. Truth is pre-defined/learned in this status. AI can't solve paradoxes as single person.

What have philosophers said about the combined efforts to love humanity and to seek truth? My version of truth is that this is a simple question that does not merit votes to close. Obviously, humans do not agree on the truth, even if we all claim to value truth. Further, humans do not agree on the meaning of love, and if one advocates the love of all humanity then a person claiming to be more rational will insist that such value or effort is irrational.

I would recommend a healthy degree of skepticism when reading what philosophers have to say on AI. There's a lot of stuff out there that's of...questionable relevance to any real system. As a quick rule of thumb: always remember that AI is a branch of mathematics. If a paper that purports to be about AI doesn't include any math, it's probably not worth reading.

@Ray - I am in favor of people publishing and reading AI math models. I don't know if math models will enable machines to emergently generate and recognize universal love for humans or conscious evaluations of truth! My question is about love and truth in human ethical philosophy. Jesus, in the Gospel of John, says, "I will send you another advocate: the spirit of truth." Christians associate values of love and truth with religious concepts of God, Jesus, and the Holy Spirit aka The Paraclete. If general AI emerges it will need conscious emotions to feel love for humans and search for truth.

Preamble
I'll focus on LLMs (large-language models, like ChatGPT) since that type of AI model is most relevant to this conversation. One might imagine more superior AI where some of the points below no longer apply, but LLMs are the state-of-the-art at the time of writing.
For more advanced AI that is more autonomous and more intelligent and has more unmoderated access to act in the world, that's well into the realm of sci-fi speculation.
You can influence an LLM to behave one way or another by training it on different data, by changing its architecture, by giving it different prompts, etc. This goes deep into computer science, more so than philosophy.
Wanting it to behave in certain ways could be grounded in philosophy / ethics, so let's consider that.


Should an LLM be able to give laypeople detailed instructions for how to make high-yield biological weapons using household products that could kill millions of people? (Putting aside the question of whether that's even possible.)
I would say "absolutely not".
From a utilitarian perspective, it is hard to imagine any upside of LLMs, that would outweigh such a severe downside.
If nothing else, we should construct the models so as to avoid it from giving such instructions, even if it makes the model significantly worse (as long as the overall effect of the model is still positive, or it seems reasonable to think it is so). This might mean keeping such things out of the training data, or it might mean giving certain prompts or preventing certain prompts.
Now Musk probably wouldn't advocate for the extreme that LLMs should give such information. But if we agree so far, "maximally truth-seeking" is out the window, and we'd at the very least need to caveat that. Maybe one can say LLMs should have that information, it just shouldn't give it to users, but that's a very risky bet, as there are many ways to trick LLMs. Even if we manage to develop an AI with human-level intelligence, it still wouldn't seem like the best idea to give it that information, because there are also many ways to trick humans.
If we agree that there should be some limits on what an LLM knows or what information it can give out, then one gets into a much more nuanced discussion of where exactly that line would be, what are the benefits and what are the drawbacks of moving the line in one direction or the other, in one dimension or another.
This would be a much more nuanced and technical case-by-case discussion that would be hard to answer generally, except by pointing out that sharing any and all truths may not lead to the best outcome for humanity (even if I tend to lean much more heavily than most into sharing and promoting truth as a good in and of itself).
On a similar note, there are ethics of scientific research, not only in the sense of "don't torture people in the name of science" or whatever, but also whether it's ethical to perform and publish certain research, because the answer to the research question would have little pragmatic use and might be used or misconstrued to promote e.g. racism, eugenics or genocide.
"Wokeness"?
The elephant in the room is Musk's "woke nihilism" and "politically correct" accusations, that's very relevant to what he says about this, and it's paraphrased in the question. So I can't really write an answer without addressing that.
He says AIs are being "taught to say crazy things in some cases, that are very troubling".
And he follows up from the above by saying he wants a "maximally truth-seeking" AI that cares about humanity.
The implication is that the "crazy" and "troubling" things (in his words) that AIs are specifically taught to say, are (a) not true, and (b) a result of "woke politically correct nihilism".
One could probably spend hours digging into the baggage and hidden meaning behind just the 4 single words that are the dog whistles / weasel words of "woke", "nihilism", and "politically correct".
But that's beyond philosophy, and just address that somewhat briefly:
Musk can only be said to interested in "a maximally truth-seeking AI that cares about humanity" if (a) you agree with him on what is true, and (b) you agree with him on what's best for humanity. This boils down to agreeing that "wokeness" etc. is anti-truth and anti-humanity, even though for the progressive ideas he's presumably referring to, much of that (particularly parts relating truth) is supported by the overwhelming consensus of scientists and scientific organisations, while the rest is grounded specifically in concern for people.
Needless to say, I do not agree with Musk's position, and I instead go with the consensus of scientists and with empathy and with humanism. From my perspective, the situation is the exact opposite of what he says, in that he's the one moving away from truth and away from concern for humanity.
Musk has fallen pretty deep down the anti-"woke" conspiracy theory rabbit hole, along with way too many people on the right (the right uses the term "woke" about 100 times more often than any of the supposedly "woke" people they're talking about, but few of those on the right can actually explain what they mean by it). Some of them have pretty openly declared a war against the idea of empathy and against minorities and against the idea of showing concern for minorities, which I can appreciate if only in the sense that it makes it far easier to show how atrocious that is. Whereas others skirt around such ideas using weasel words, trying to convince others, or just themselves, that they care about people, even as they try to take people's rights away, erase them from society and prevent them from learning about themselves and having access to things that would improve their lives, which we have extensive evidence is the case. Having good intentions isn't enough to stop one's misguided actions from causing real harm to real people.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

A few pointers:
I think the problem you are referring to is more generally known as AI alignment. Philosophers that have written about AI alignment are Nick Bostrom (from simulation hypothesis fame), Hans Jonas (on the who is responsible question) and Gabriel Iason (who works at Google's DeepMind but has a philosophical background).

I am asking about the human philosophers who advocate love and truth. I am not asking about the AI alignment problem although I am arguing that not even humans are all aligned with the values of universal love for humans and seeking truth, so yes, I am skeptical of technocrats ability to identify and solve the so-called AI alignment problem.
